# How is an Event-based Container App invoked?

Tags: azure, containers, azure-container-instances

I am a bit confused as to how to develop a C# application that will run in a Container App and respond to messages in a Service Bus topic.

I have previously worked with event-based Azure Functions and in my mind, they are the same, just that Container App is exclusively containers based.

In Azure Functions, I can have a `Run()` method with a `[Function]` attribute and the `ServiceBusTrigger` attribute on the function parameter. Then when a message is added to the topic, Azure Functions will take care of invoking my Function passing along the message to my function's entry point.

I'm looking for a similar invocation model, where my app or my app's entry point is triggered by KEDA(?), or DAPR(?) when a message is added to the topic.

However, the examples I've seen create a `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.BackgroundService` worker and then create a "message pump" that subscribes the worker to the Topic subscription. So, the container is constantly running and it is the one responsible for listening to new messages. Which was not what I was expecting.

Seeing how the pricing model is similar to how Azure Functions is billed (vCPU, Memory, and Requests), I imagined that the container was invoked on each request.

It seems like KEDA is only responsible for scaling the Container App up and down, but not for invoking the container when a new event is received.

Please let me know if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event-based container app approach-
The container is responsible for listening to events and responding to them. And it doesn't follow the on-demand invocation model of Azure Functions, where the platform takes care of invoking your function when a trigger event occurs.

Instead, in a container-based scenario, you need to create a long-running process within the container that subscribes to the events and reacts to them. This is typically achieved by creating a background service or worker that continuously polls or listens for events.
Steps to create a long-running process within a container.

- Create container Image using Docker.

[image]

Docker File

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:4 AS base
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["testingFun/testingFun.csproj", "testingFun/"]
RUN dotnet restore "testingFun/testingFun.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/testingFun"
RUN dotnet build "testingFun.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "testingFun.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
```

[image]

- Choose the Service bus Topic.

[image]

- Use the [Dotnet SDK to connect the Event source.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/eventsource-getting-started)
- And subscribe to events
- Run the process.

> The examples you've seen that use `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.BackgroundService` and create a "message pump" are following this approach.

The container stays running, and the worker inside the container is responsible for listening to new messages from the Service Bus topic. This setup allows the worker to continuously process events as they arrive.

**KEDA** is used for automatic scaling of Kubernetes workloads based on event driven metrics.

**Dapr** is a runtime that simplifies the development of microservices-based applications.

> In an event-based container app approach, the container stays running, and you need to implement a background service or worker inside the container to subscribe to events and handle them as they arrive. KEDA and Dapr can be used alongside container apps to provide additional capabilities like scaling and pub/sub messaging, respectively, but they don't handle the event invocation directly.

For more information refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/custom-event-quickstart-portal).